# How to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{c^\prime}{\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert_2}\bigg)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Consider an interval $I = [t_0,t_1]$ and let $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$ and let  $V \subseteq \mathcal{C}^{1}(I,X)$ be the set of all curves $c:I \rightarrow X$ where $(t,c(t),c^\prime(t))$ is contained in $U$ for all $t$.
> Solve the boundary value problem
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{c^\prime}{\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert_2}\bigg) = 0$$
>
> with $c(t_0) = x_0, c(t_1) = x_1$. Remark: The norm of in $\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert_2$ is the Eulcidean norm.

I am new to differential equations, so here are my thoughts: I tried to take the line $c$ through $x_0$ and $x_1$, i.e.:

$$c(t) := x_0 + \frac{t-t_0}{t_1-t_0} \cdot (x_1-x_0)$$

, and thus

$$c^\prime (t) = \frac{-t_0}{t_1-t_0} \cdot (x_1-x_0).$$

This obviously fullfills the boundary conditions $c(t_0) = x_0$ and $c(t_1) = x_1$. However, I am not quite sure how to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt} \big( \frac{c^\prime}{\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert}\big)$ now. I would be tempted to say that, since there is no parameter left in $c^\prime$ and thus also in $\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert$, we have $\frac{d}{dt} \big( \frac{c^\prime}{\lvert\lvert c^\prime \rvert\rvert}\big) = 0$. Could you please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Since $c^\prime (t)$ is a constant vector (i.e. does not depend on t) then so is $\frac{c^\prime}{||c^\prime||}$, which means that it's derivative is 0.